# How to disable future dates in bsdatePicker

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using bsdatepicker in my angular project and i want to disable all future dates in that datePicker for the DOB selection

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'demo-datepicker-datesdisabled',
  templateUrl: './disable-dates.html'
})
export class DemoDatepickerDatesDisabledComponent {
  disabledDates = [
    new Date('2019-02-05'),
    new Date('2019-02-09')
  ];
}



<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-12 col-md-4 form-group">
    <input type="text"
           placeholder="Datepicker"
           class="form-control"
           bsDatepicker
           [datesDisabled]="disabledDates">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-12 col-md-4 form-group">
    <input type="text"
           placeholder="Daterangepicker"
           class="form-control"
           bsDaterangepicker
           [datesDisabled]="disabledDates">
  </div>
</div>
```

the above code is working but i want to disable future N number of date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `[maxDate]` to today.

```
<input type="text"
           placeholder="Daterangepicker"
           class="form-control"
           bsDaterangepicker
           [datesDisabled]="disabledDates"
           [maxDate]="today"
>
```

```
public today = new Date();
```